# How to visualize limit order book in gui? What Library or widgets to use?

Tags: limit-order-book, visualization

I have implemented a very simple limit order book in c++ . I would like to visualize it in a GUI application. I don't any experience in GUI. What library and widget may be used? Any suggestion in this regard will be helpful.
Is there any special widget or library?

Thanks

Comment: What language do you prefer?

Comment: I have written the limit order book in c++. The GUI should also be preferably in c++ .

Comment: You would like to represent the order book something like this?  https://library.tradingtechnologies.com/trade/Content/mdt-market-data1.png It may be difficult to find in the public domain, Trading Technologies claims a patent on this type of GUI display.

Comment: Yes. The UI may be somewhat similar to that but not exactly like that.

Comment: Use QT and then look for the QTableWidget